# Creating a customized "Yes / No" alert box in asp.net (javascript) - Part 2

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net-3.5, webforms

I am trying to create a customized messagebox using javascript but not getting too far.

```
    string txtConfirmMessage = "On " + DateTime.Now + ", ";
    txtConfirmMessage = txtConfirmMessage + sUserID;
    txtConfirmMessage = txtConfirmMessage + " added this record. Do you want to continue? ";
    btnSubmit.OnClientClick = @"return confirm('" + txtConfirmMessage + "' Do you want to continue);";
```

I need to display a custom message involving the UserID, the date, and the value that the user has enetered. When I click the Submit button, the messagebox does not pop up.

**Update:**
I know this code is executed at the Page_Load event. However, is it possible to display in this alert box, a value that the user has selected (that action occurs after the page load event) ?

Any ideas to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javascript that you have is not valid, as the "confirm" method taks a single parameter, but you are giving it two bits.

Try this modified version.

```
string messageFormat = "On {0}, {1} added this record.  Do you want to continue?";
string formattedMessage = string.format(messageFormat, DateTime.Now, sUserID);
btnSubmit.OnClientClick = "return confirm('" + formattedMessage + "');";
```

Comment: I know this code is executed at the Page_Load event. However, is it possible to display in this alert box, a value that the user has selected (that action occurs after the page load event) ?

Comment: You could use a hidden field and retrieve that value with javascript

Answer (score 2):

You just have an extra string after the one you're passing to [`confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.confirm), change it to this:

```
btnSubmit.OnClientClick = @"return confirm('" + txtConfirmMessage + "');";
```

Answer (score 1):

About the update of the question, you could assign an OnClientClick event handler to the button as late as PreRender and the value will be persisted in the ViewState.